# Visualizing customized IOB tags with SpaCy DisplaCy

Tags: python, spacy, named-entity-recognition, spacy-3

I have a text file that I have created a DOC object from using SpaCy:

```
doc = nlp.make_doc(raw_text)
```

I also have a list of customized IOP tags for each word in this DOC object:

```
['O', 'B-PER', 'I-PER', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'B-DATE', 'I-DATE', 'I-DATE', 'I-DATE', 'I-DATE', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'B-ORG', 'I-ORG']
```

I want to assign each one of these tags to each word in the DOC object and visualize the results using DisplaCy (The Length of the tag list is equal to the length of the doc object):

```
 displacy.render(doc, style="ent", jupyter=True)
```

However, I do not know how to achieve this. I have used the `doc.char_span` method for when I had the start and end index for each tag label:

```
def Visulaizer(file_name, path):
  nlp = spacy.blank("fa")
  f = open(path+'/'+file_name+'.txt', 'r')
  raw_text = f.read()
  doc = nlp.make_doc(raw_text)
  spans = tags
  ents = []
  for span_start, span_end, label in spans:
     ent = doc.char_span(span_start, span_end, label=label)
     if ent is None:
         continue
     ents.append(ent)
  doc.ents = ents
  displacy.render(doc, style="ent", jupyter=True)

visualized_data = Visulaizer('test', path)
```

How can I change my code so that it matches my current settings?

Answer (score 1):

You can only assign ents directly from IOB tags by providing the whole list at once when initializing the `Doc`. Use `Doc(ents=)`:

```py
from spacy.tokens import Doc
doc = Doc(nlp.vocab, words=words, ents=iob_tags)
```

Alternatively, you can convert IOB tags to ent spans with `spacy.training.iob_utils.biluo_tags_to_spans` and assign to `doc.ents`. However, since the default tokenizer from `nlp` might not produce the exact same words as in your original annotation, it's best to start with aligned `words` and `ents` and then you're sure the tags are aligned to the correct words.

Comment: `from spacy.tokens import Doc
def Visulaizer(file_name, path):
  nlp = spacy.blank("fa")
  f = open(path+'/'+file_name+'.txt', 'r')
  raw_text = f.read()
  words = nlp.make_doc(raw_text)
  for tags in tagArray[1]:
    Tags = tags
  iobTags = Tags
  ents = []
  ent = Doc(nlp.vocab, words=words, ents=iobTags)
  ents.append(ent)
  doc.ents = ents
  displacy.render(doc, style="ent", jupyter=True)
visualized_data = Visulaizer('test', path)`

Comment: But I received this error: TypeError: an integer is required